# One sided limit of formula involving the hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1$ at singular point

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, hypergeometric-function

I need help finding the following limit (closed form):

\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\to1^{-}}\alpha x \ln(1-x) +\frac{(\alpha+1)x^2}{2-\alpha} {_2F_1(1, 2-\alpha; 3-\alpha; x)}
\\
&\hspace{2cm}-\frac{x^2}{2-\alpha} {_2F_1(1, 2-\alpha^2; 3-\alpha^2; x)}
\end{align}

where $\alpha = e^\frac{2\pi i}{3}$ and the hypergeometric function is defined as:

$$_2F_1(a;b;c;z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a)_n (b)_n}{(c)_n}\frac{z^n}{n!}$$

where:

$$(a)_n=\begin{cases}
1,  & n=0 \\
a(a+1)...(a+n-1), & n>0
\end{cases}$$

This is the first time I even hear of a hypergeometric function so I haven't the slightest clue as to how to approach this problem.

I tried looking up some identities regarding ${_2F_1}$ but have come up with nothing useful, except the fact that it has a singularity at $1$ which really isn't helpful...

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You really should provide at least a definition of the hyper-geometric functions for other people who've never heard of them.  As it is, some people may feel that it looks rather like you're asking for help without making an effort.

Comment: what's the type of singularity at $1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hypergeometric functions you provided are a special case known as *zero-balanced*. Specifically, $F(a,b;c;x)$ is zero-balanced if $c=a+b$ and according to [DLMF 15.4.21](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.4.E21) as $x\to 1^-$:
$$
F(a,b;a+b;x)\sim-\log(1-x)\frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)},
$$
showing a logarithmic singularity at $x=1$. Consequently, if we denote
$$
f(x)=\alpha x \ln(1-x) +\frac{(\alpha+1)x^2}{2-\alpha} {_2F_1(1, 2-\alpha; 3-\alpha; x)}-\frac{x^2}{2-\alpha} {_2F_1(1, 2-\alpha^2; 3-\alpha^2; x)},
$$
then as $x\to 1^-$:
$$
f(x)\sim \alpha x\log (1-x)-(\alpha+1)x^2\log(1-x)+\frac{2-\alpha ^2}{2-\alpha}x^2 \log (1-x),
$$
which diverges in the limit.

Mathematica:

```
\[Alpha] = Exp[2 Pi I/3];
f[x_] := \[Alpha] x Log[1 - x] + (\[Alpha] + 1)/(2 - \[Alpha])
     x^2 Hypergeometric2F1[1, 2 - \[Alpha], 3 - \[Alpha], x] - 
   1/(2 - \[Alpha])
     x^2 Hypergeometric2F1[1, 2 - \[Alpha]^2, 3 - \[Alpha]^2, x];
Plot[Abs[f[x]], {x, 0.5, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn’t the third term be divided by $2-\alpha^2$ rather than $2-\alpha$?  That may change the graph and the conclusion.

Comment: @WADon I don't think so.  Look back at the OPs post.  The third term is divided by $2-\alpha$. Furthermore, $F(1,2-\alpha^2;3-\alpha^2;x)\sim -(2-\alpha^2)\log(1-x)$.  Agree?

Comment: Yes, I misread OP question.